# How to get places details within the specific direction and distance radius using camera and compass?

Tags: ios, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have a very specific requirement. What I am looking for is, when a user open the camera and place it to any direction and he wants to see the place details (depends on user input) if exist with in the range user wants to see (for example, in 1 km radius). How can we achieve this? Please guide me on this.

I had gone through google places API. But I am wondering that would it work with the direction data which we can get from Core location API.

Comment: you mean like the phone camera ?

Comment: Yes u r right. We have to use phone camera.